# Как перемещать мышкой QWidget на QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsproxywidget

Подскажите как перемещать мышкой `QWidget` на `QGraphicsScene`?

**Sample1_ui.py** (из QtDesigner):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1119, 830)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 811, 561))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1119, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

**Sample1.py**:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QLabel, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor
from Sample1_ui import *
import sys


class Mainwindow_S1(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500), QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0)))
        label = self.scene.addWidget(QLabel('123456'))
        label.setGeometry(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
        label.setPos(10, 10)
        label.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        label.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphics_view = Mainwindow_S1()
    graphics_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При добавлении `self.scene.addWidget` возвращается `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, но для него почему-то не работают флаги `ItemIsMovable` и `ItemIsSelectable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, \
    QLabel, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor

#from Sample1_ui import *
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1119, 830)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 811, 561))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1119, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.startPos = None
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 30)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Container {
                background: lightblue;
                border: 0px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        ''')
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):                                  
        if self.startPos:
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.startPos))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = None        
        

class GraphicsRoundedFrame(QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.container = Container()    
        self.setWidget(self.container)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        self.container.layout().addWidget(widget)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget):
        qp.save()
        p = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p.addRoundedRect(self.boundingRect().adjusted(0, 0, -.5, -.5), 4, 4)
        qp.setClipPath(p)
        super().paint(qp, opt, widget)
        qp.restore()
        

class Mainwindow_S1(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
       
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500), QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0)))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        testFrame = GraphicsRoundedFrame()
        self.scene.addItem(testFrame)

        testFrame.container.layout().addStretch(1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/_Qt/__Qt/lena.jpg").scaled(100, 100))
        testFrame.addWidget(self.label_2)
        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'D:/_Qt/__Qt/lena.jpg', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))
        testFrame.container.layout().addStretch(1)
        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Просто кнопка'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphics_view = Mainwindow_S1()
    graphics_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]